# return value jquery function

Tags: jquery

With the below code it should alert 'one' and then 'two'. Only 'one' is alerted when i press `.button`.  The var `got` is not being returned to the `.button` function.

```
$('.button').live('click',function() {
var got = fetchvalue('100');

   if(got==1) {
    alert('two');

   }

});


function fetchvalue(id) {

    $.getJSON('/fetchvalue.php?id='+id+'&w=1',function(data) {

alert('one');       
    var got=1;                  

    });

    return got;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`getJSON` is async, which means it is impossible to get the return value immediately in this invocation statement, so your code should be:

```
$('.button').live('click',function() {
    fetchvalue('100', function(got) { // add a callback
        if (got == 1) {
            alert('two');
        }
    });
});


function fetchvalue(id, callback) {
    $.getJSON('/fetchvalue.php?id='+id+'&w=1',function(data) {
        alert('one');       
        var got=1;
        callback(got); // invoke the callback
    });

    // no return is required
}
```

Comment: according to http://api.jquery.com/live/   "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()".

Answer (score 0):

That's because your variable `got` is scoped to your JSON return function (i.e. you can't access it outside of the JSON callback function), plus JSON loads asynchronously. You could use an $.ajax call and set async to false, which has the same effect but without asynchronous loading, which means any variables you set inside the callback won't be (effectively) scoped to it.

```
function fetchvalue(id) {
    var got;
    $.ajax({

        url: '/fetchvalue.php?id=' + id + '&w=1',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: myData,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('one');
            got = 1;
        }
    });

    return got;
}​
```

Comment: This won't work as the function in the getJSON call is called asynchronously when the ajax call has completed, which is one of the issues with the original code.

Comment: I've edited to reflect your comment, thanks for pointing that out.